# Wrap a general function to take it's arguments from a string

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I wish to create a wrapper around a general function, T0 f(T1, T2, T3 ...) automatically which pulls that function's arguments from strings on a stack (converted to the appropriate types), and does something with the return value. My ideal outcome will be realised if I can do something like the following pseudo-ish code:

```
#include <stack>
std::stack<char*> argStack;
std::stack<char*> retStack;


int add(float a, float b){
    return a+b;
}
int main(){
    argStack.push((char*)"2");
    argStack.push((char*)"5");
    auto wrapped=funcWrap(add);
    wrapped();
    std::cout << retStack.top();
    return 0;
}
```

and this will print "7" on stdout.

Some time ago I spent some days looking at SO and came up with something like the following (compilable):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <tuple>
#include "apply_tuple.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
std::stack<string> argStack;
std::stack<string> retStack;

template<typename T>
T getNextArg(){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(argStack.top());
    argStack.pop();
    T convertedVar;
    ss >> convertedVar;
    return convertedVar;
}

template <typename Fn, typename funcSig> struct funcWrap;  

template <typename Fn, typename R, typename ...Args>
struct funcWrap<Fn, R(Args...)>       // specialized for typename = R(Args...)
{
    using funcType= Fn;
    funcType *wrappedFunc;

    funcWrap(funcType &inputFunc){
        this->wrappedFunc=&inputFunc;
    }
    void operator()(){
        auto tup =std::make_tuple(getNextArg<Args>()...);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << apply_tuple(*wrappedFunc, tup);
        retStack.push(ss.str());
    }
};

int add(float a, float b){
    return a+b;
}

int main(){
    argStack.push(string("2"));
    argStack.push(string("5"));
    auto wrapped=funcWrap<decltype(add), decltype(add)>(add);
    wrapped();
    cout << retStack.top();
    return 0;
}
```

Where apply_tuple is from https://www.preney.ca/paul/archives/1099. It simply calls the function pointer with the arguments contained in the supplied tuple.

I've been using a fancier version of this pattern for a while (mostly to automatically generate an interface to debug code running on an arduino), and it works nicely, but it has 2 major problems I'm beating myself up trying to fix: it's redundant (in that I write the function name 3 times in the wrapping process), and it doesn't work for member functions. Is it possible to remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your primary issue is building the function object. The easiest approach avoiding repeated specification of the function and to cover member functions is to use a factory function deducing the relevant types. Appropriately overloading this function can easily distinguish between normal and member functions. I assume the duplicate use of the function type is for function objects where the type of the representation and the signature actually differ.

```
template <typename R, typename... A>
funcWrap<R(A...), R(*)(A...)>
wrap(R(*fun)(A...)) { // deal with functions
    return funcWrap<R(A...), R(*)(A...)>(fun);
}
template <typename Signature, typename F>
funcWrap<Signature, F>
wrap(F&& f) { // deal with function objects
    return funcWrap<Signature, F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
template <typename R, typename S, typename... A>
funcWrap<R(S&, A...), R (S::*)(A...)>
wrap(R(S::*mem)(A...)) {
    return funcWrap<R(S&, A...), R (S::*)(A...)>(mem);
}
```

You'd use the `wrap()` function like this

```
 float add(float, float);
 struct adder { float operator()(float, float); };
 struct foo { foo mem(foo); };

 int main() {
     auto wfun = wrap(&add);
     auto wobj = wrap<float(float, float)>(adder());
     auto wmem = wrap(&foo::mem);
 }
```

You'll need to deal with conjuring up a suitable object to call your member on and you'll probably need some specializations of your function wrapper `funcWrap`. Also, for the member function case you might need to have suitable overloads for `const` member functions. For member functions it may also make sense to specify the object when wrapping the member and capture it appropriately. Using `std::bind()` or lambda function member functions could also be bound using the wrapper for the function objects but this most likely requires specifying the signature which can otherwise be deduced.

Below is a complete demo compiling with C++11 showing all the bits and bobs needed to make this wrapping work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T>
typename std::decay<T>::type makeArg(std::stack<std::string>& args) {
    typename std::decay<T>::type rc;
    if (args.empty() || !(std::istringstream(args.top()) >> rc)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("can't create argument from '" + (args.empty()? "<empty>": args.top()) + "'");
    }
    args.pop();
    return rc;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace util
{
    template<typename T, T...>
    struct integer_sequence {
    };
    template<std::size_t... I>
    using index_sequence = integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>;

    template <typename T, std::size_t N, T... I>
    struct integer_sequencer {
        using type = typename integer_sequencer<T, N - 1, N - 1, I...>::type;
    };
    template <typename T, T... I>
    struct integer_sequencer<T, 0, I...> {
        using type =  integer_sequence<T, I...>;
    };

    template<typename T, T N>
    using make_integer_sequence = typename integer_sequencer<T, N>::type;
    template<std::size_t N>
    using make_index_sequence = make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>;

    template <typename F, typename T, std::size_t... I>
    auto apply_aux(F&& fun, T&& tuple, index_sequence<I...>) -> decltype(fun(std::get<I>(tuple)...)) {
        return fun(std::get<I>(tuple)...);
    }

    template <typename F, typename T>
    auto apply(F&& f, T&& t)
        -> decltype(apply_aux(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<T>(t), make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<T>::type>::value>())) {
        return apply_aux(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<T>(t), make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<T>::type>::value>());
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename S, typename F> class funcWrap;

template <typename R, typename... A, typename F>
class funcWrap<R(A...), F> {
private:
    F fun;

public:
    funcWrap(F fun): fun(fun) {}

    std::string operator()(std::stack<std::string>& args) {
        std::tuple<typename std::decay<A>::type...> t{ makeArg<A>(args)... };
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << util::apply(this->fun, t);
        return out.str();
    }
};

template <typename R, typename... A, typename S, typename... B>
class funcWrap<R(A...), R (S::*)(B...)> {
private:
    R (S::*mem)(B...);

public:
    funcWrap(R (S::*mem)(B...)): mem(mem) {}

    std::string operator()(std::stack<std::string>& args) {
        std::tuple<typename std::decay<A>::type...> t{ makeArg<A>(args)... };
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << util::apply([=](S& s, B... b){ return (s.*(this->mem))(b...); }, t);
        return out.str();
    }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename R, typename... A>
funcWrap<R(A...), R(*)(A...)>
wrap(R(*fun)(A...)) { // deal with functions
    return funcWrap<R(A...), R(*)(A...)>(fun);
}
template <typename Signature, typename F>
funcWrap<Signature, F>
wrap(F&& f) { // deal with function objects
    return funcWrap<Signature, F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
template <typename R, typename S, typename... A>
funcWrap<R(S&, A...), R (S::*)(A...)>
wrap(R(S::*mem)(A...)) {
    return funcWrap<R(S&, A...), R (S::*)(A...)>(mem);
}

float add(float f0, float f1) { return f0 + f1; }
struct adder {
    float value;
    explicit adder(float value): value(value) {}
    float operator()(float f0, float f1) {
        return value + f0 + f1;
    }
};
struct foo {
    float value;
    foo(): value() {}
    explicit foo(float value): value(value) {}
    foo mem(foo f) { return foo(value + f.value); }
};

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, foo& f) {
    return in >> f.value;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, foo const& f) {
    return out << f.value;
}

int main() {
    std::stack<std::string> args;

    auto wfun = wrap(&add);
    args.push("17.5");
    args.push("42.25");
    std::cout << "wfun result=" << wfun(args) << "\n";

    auto wobj = wrap<float(float, float)>(adder(3.125));
    args.push("17.5");
    args.push("42.25");
    std::cout << "wobj result=" << wobj(args) << "\n";

    auto wmem = wrap(&foo::mem);
    args.push("17.5");
    args.push("42.25");
    std::cout << "wmem result=" << wmem(args) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can't yet get this to compile (gcc 4.8, with -c++1y), despite fixing a couple of typos  (e.g. operator()(float,float) for the adder). Your approach makes perfect sense to me however. It's just the details which, as usual with templates, are doing funny things to my brain.

Comment: @user3849418: yes, there were a few typos: I had cobbled the code together on a mobile phone. I have added a complete implementation showing that this approach does work.

Comment: Oh wow. I'm ... in awe. This compiles, and does exactly what I asked for and need. I won't pretend I understand it fully just now, but I'll work on it and I suspect will learn a heck of a lot in the process. Thank you.